# Mongoose-How to specify more than one attribute value in querys?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this mongoose query and I want to add the condition estadoPedido:"Agendado" to it? How can I do it?

```
Request.countDocuments(
    { estadoPedido: "Pendente", paciente: req.body.paciente }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question right, you need to search for documents which have

```
 - estadoPedido = 'Pendente' or 'Agendado'
 - and paciente = req.body.paciente
```

you can use $in operator, something like this

```
Request.countDocuments({ 
    estadoPedido: { $in: ['Pendente', 'Agendado'] }, 
    paciente: req.body.paciente 
})
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can also add multiple where clauses

```
Request.countDocuments()
            .where("estadoPedido")
            .in(['Pendente', 'Agendado'])
            .where("prop2")
            .in(["val1","val2"])
```